# return json error on asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, json

I m trying to test an error in Json notation, via an ajax call. This is my server method

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string publicarError()
        {            
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("error");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> error = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                error.Add("success", false);
                error.Add("message", "Something really bad happened");
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);
                return output;

            }
        }
```

This is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pageUrl + '/publicarError',
                data: '{valor: ' + $('#<%=classroomDropDownList.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { alert('ok'); },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {

                    var json = xhr.responseText;
                    var result = [];
                    result = eval('(' + json + ')');
                    var errorMessages = [];
                    //this ugly loop is because List<> is serialized to an object instead of an array
                    for (var key in result) {
                        errorMessages.push(result[key]);
                    }
                    $('#result').html(errorMessages.join("<br />"));
                },
```

But when I run the example , it always enter on succes function, and not on the error one.

I dont know why. Is there any mistake?

Comment: JQuery is only looking for a valid response.  Your method is returning valid JSON as a part of the Exception, and it's not changing the HttpStatus, so JQuery isn't going to know the difference.  If you alert JSON.Stringify(result) from inside your success(result) function in your ajax call, you will probably get your error object.

Comment: Its a good point, I ll try watching the alert. HttpStatusCode I cant change because the method is static. So I dont know how to access to Context.Response.StatusCode in a static method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour. You are not returning an error, you are returning a valid JSON object, so it goes to the `success` function. To go to the `error` function, you need to throw an exception. Comment out the `try ... catch` and the `throw new Exception("error");` will go to the `error` function.

Comment: But when I do this , an unhandled exception message apears in visual studio. Its ok that? or I have to put another try and catch somewhere

Comment: @emmanuelsio Do you mean in debug mode? Yes, that's ok. As long as you only call this method by Ajax. If you call `publicarError()` function by some other C# code, you can put surround it with `try...catch` right there.

Comment: It works your answer. I dont like very much the idea to make crash trhowing a new exception where nobody catches. Is a good practice to do that?

Comment: @emmanuelsio I'm not sure I understand your question. The best practice is: You only catch an exception for two reasons: 1) to handle it appropriately right in that spot. 2) to protect the sensitive information and provide a new error that does not reveal sensitive information, or to provide additional information. In your code, you're just throwing "error" text with no sensitive info, so there is no point in catching it and throwing another info. If you need more info, change the `Exception("error")` to include all the info you need.